# Shadow Missing in Mobile

Tags: css, mobile, concrete5

Working on the following page: http://tinyurl.com/o3jpxgf

I noticed that when I resize the window to be smaller, (ie tablet or mobile size) I get a broken image. I've inspected with Firebug and the image that it calls for is in that file structure. Double checked via FTP that there is an appropriate file in the directory. Don't understand why it's broken. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the link to the image should be:

```
http://crystalrock.biz/croutlet/application/themes/crystalrock/images/homepage-callout-shadow-sm.png
```

Instead of

```
http://crystalrock.biz/application/themes/crystalrock/images/homepage-callout-shadow-sm.png
```

You're missing the `/croutlet/` from the url

Comment: I added the croutlet throughout the CSS, only to find that the original theme editor placed the image in the header file. Maddening, but thank you for the help!